# tool to create and send test udp datagrams

Tags: networking, udp

im looking for sth like:

```
udpsend [udp-data] [target-ip] [target-port]
```

eg.

```
c:\>udpsend "Hello, World" 192.168.1.111 4711
```

this should be out there anywhere, but i cant find it.

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) can do that. It's a UNIX tool, but I believe there is a Windows version.

Answer (score 1):

would [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) do it ?

[sourceforge](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

`iperf` can do that, see `--fileinput` command line parameter.